# how send out session(variable) before php loop?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I use

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

to print all sql result.

and I have a button for each row...
" onclick="Pos.action='wantToRent.php';Pos.submit();">
to convey value immediately to other page.
and if I try convey next value likes:

```
<?php $_SESSION['SID']= $row[7];?>
```

or

```
<input type=hidden name=SID value="<?php echo $row[7];?>">
```

it will be influence by loop and convey the last value $row[7] of table...

how I get the correct SID of row without influence?

full code:

```
  <form name = "Pos" action = ""  method = "post">
  <?php 
  include('phpfile/db_connect.php');
  $sql = " SELECT * FROM product";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql); 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){?>
    <div class='proList'>
      <h3 class='proTitle'><a href='https://www.google.com'><?php echo $row[1];?></a></h3>
      <div class='proleft pro'><img src='' alt='abc'/></div>
      <div class='proright pro'><a class='seller protxt' href='https://www.google.com'> <?php echo $row[2];?> </a>
        <div class='proPri protxt'> <?php echo $row[3];?> </div>
        <div class='proTim protxt'> <?php echo $row[4];?> </div>
        <div class='proPosi protxt'> <?php echo $row[5];?> </div>
        <div class='proDeti protxt'><?php $row[6];?> </div><br/>
        <button name="iwantR" value="<?php echo $row[0];?>" onclick="Pos.action='wantToRent.php';Pos.submit();">rent</button>
        <?php $_SESSION['SID']= $row[7];?> //where I try send out SID without loop influence.
      </div>
    </div>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  </form>
```

Comment: can you show more code (in context)? It's unclear what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for the full code. Now: What do you want to be stored in `$_SESSION['SID']`? The first value, the last?

Comment: ok, I think I got your problem: put the form _inside_ the loop and add the hidden input again.

Comment: _OR_ change the button to a simple `<a href="wantToRent.php?sid=<?php echo $row[7]; ?>">rent me</a>` and get that val in `wantToRent` in `$_GET['sid']`

Comment: oh I have try put the form loop and it make onclick action not work(it wouldn't jump into wantToRent.php).

Comment: there's no need for that javascript. Just put the action into the form tag.

Comment: and i don't get your second solution... it's just make button change into href ? button line code is success and I don't make it change. I just want the next line $row[7] into right correspond...put it simple,I want make two row convey to next page,I just a one chance to click and jump into other page and  left the other be influence by loop